# How do I specify arrays in .env files for Ghost?

Tags: ghost-blog, dotenv

How do I specify array values for Ghost's .env file?

I am using a [`.env` file to configure Ghost](https://ghost.org/docs/config/). Per [How to define array/object in .env file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846589/how-to-define-array-object-in-env-file) I have set up a line in my `.env` which reads:

```
logging__transports="file,stdout"
```

However Ghost fails with:

> TypeError: this.transports.splice is not a function

**How do I specify arrays in .env files for Ghost?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghost [now supports this](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/8940#issuecomment-426790527):

```
logging__transports='["file", "stdout"]'
```